# Compare excel sheets from two excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a freeware that is portable (do not require to be install) and can compare two excel sheets that come from two different excel file. It will highlight the different by showing which cells is different)

Example:
There are two sheets (named `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`) in the first excel file (named `Excel1.xls`)

There is this second excel file (named `Excel2.xls`) that contain one sheets (named `SheetZ`)

Inside `Sheet1`, there is data occupy on the first two row and two column.

Inside `Sheet2`, there is no data.

Inside `SheetZ`, there is data occupy on the first 3 rows and 3 column. (Only the 1st cell have the same data as the 1st cell in `Sheet1`)

So, when I do a compare of the excel sheets from the two excel files, the software will generate a report as follows:

**Data Difference**

- `Excel1.xls` (1st Sheet)

  - `Sheet1` B1
  - `Sheet1` C1
  - `Sheet1` A2
  - `Sheet1` B2
  - `Sheet1` C2
  - `Sheet1` A3
  - `Sheet1` B3
  - `Sheet1` C3
- `Excel2.xls` (1st Sheet)

  - `SheetZ` B1
  - `SheetZ` C1
  - `SheetZ` A2
  - `SheetZ` B2
  - `SheetZ` C2
  - `SheetZ` A3
  - `SheetZ` B3
  - `SheetZ` C3

**Same Data**

- 1st Sheet A1

It may not be the exact report as shown above, as long as it can compare excel sheets from two different excel file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare Sheets seems to fit the description:

> Compare Sheets is a **free** software that can **compare two Excel sheets**
>   and display the results of comparison in another sheet. It’s a
>   lightweight and **portable** app that works independently of Microsoft
>   Excel and does file comparison without having to install Excel or
>   other similar app in your system.

- [Review](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/27/windows/business/office/compare-sheets-free-software-to-compare-ms-excel-sheets.html)
- [Software](http://www.nezavisim.com/?cat=2&scat=8)

Also, consider reviewing ExelDiff:

> ExelDiff is a **free** tool that can **compare Excel files** and figure out
>   the differences between them. It’s an extremely simple and easy to use
>   tool that compares two excel spreadsheets and save the results in html
>   format. ExcelDiff produces comprehensive results and highlight all
>   cells that have difference in values. ExcelDiff is a **portable** app that
>   runs without prior installation.

[Software](http://msws.co/en/product03.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

[BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) can compare excel sheets, in addition to a host of other file formats, folders, and even directories over ftp/sftp.  I use it just about daily.  But unlike the other solutions it costs $30 to $50.

Answer (score 1):

The **free version** of JuxtAPPose only compares spreadsheets and doesn't require installation, however, it only do it one tab at a time (1st spreadsheet in the file, so you have to move all the way to the left the spreadsheet/tab you want to compare on each file):

Demo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBBtqQ_AxMs&t

Page
https://www.juxtappose.com/pricing